# QGIS 3D viewer autoupdate frames from temporal controller

Tags: qgis, dem, 3d, time, flood

I am using QGIS 3.30.3 and I am trying to make a cinematic with the 3D viewer of some flood tiles.

I have a Digital elevation Model and a few flood tiles with temporal information. Using the temporal controller, I can see the tiles sequence, nevertheless, on my 3D viewer those changes aren't showed up. There is a way to autoupdate the 3D viewer to also show the tiles sequence?

Any idea or suggestion?

[image]